# How to read NTFS permissions in a list of shares from a text file

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, permissions

I am trying to get it easier to use on file servers. I would like to import a file called `shares.txt`. In that `shares.txt` there are for example lines, e.g. folder name → root folder and share name → subfolder.

```
\\10.10.15.240\folder name\share name
\\10.10.15.240\folder name\share2 name
\\10.10.15.240\folder name\share3 name

\\10.10.15.240\folder2 name\share name
\\10.10.15.240\folder2 name\share2 name
\\10.10.15.240\folder2 name\share3 name
```

and so on.

And I would like to create the output to:
Outputs the data to a text file on `\\10.10.15.240\output\` using the folder name and share name as part of the file name

```
\\10.10.15.240\output\Company_name_$folder name_$share name.csv
\\10.10.15.240\output\Company_name_$folder name_$share2 name.csv
\\10.10.15.240\output\Company_name_$folder name_$share3 name.csv

\\10.10.15.240\output\Company_name_$folder2 name_$share name.csv
\\10.10.15.240\output\Company_name_$folder2 name_$share2 name.csv
\\10.10.15.240\output\Company_name_$folder2 name_$share3 name.csv
```

and continue.

Do you know how to import this in your script? I tried several things but they all comes up with errors.

Script:

I want to write the permissions list to a CSV file instead of writing it directly to Excel.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
$a = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 
$a.visible = $true
$b = $a.Workbooks.Add()
$intRow = 1
$c = $b.Worksheets.Item(1)
$c.Cells.Item($intRow,1) = "Folder"
$c.Cells.Item($intRow,2) = "Compte/groupe"
$c.Cells.Item($intRow,3) = "Type d'Acces"
$c.Cells.Item($intRow,4) = "Droits"
$d = $c.UsedRange
$d.EntireColumn.AutoFit()|Out-Null
$d.Interior.ColorIndex = 19
$d.Font.ColorIndex = 11
$d.Font.Bold = $true
Remove-Variable arrayOfPath
$depth = 2
$RootFolder = "\\MySRV\Folder"
for ($i=0; $i -le $depth; $i++) {
  $arrayOfPath += ,$RootFolder
  $RootFolder = $RootFolder + "\*"
}
$arrayOfPath | Get-ChildItem | %{
  Get-Acl $_.FullName
} | %{
  $intRow = $intRow + 1
  $c.Cells.Item($intRow, 1) = $_.Path.ToString().Replace("Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::", "")
  $droit = $_.Access
  $droit | %{
    $c.Cells.Item($intRow, 2) = $_.IdentityReference.ToString();
    $c.Cells.Item($intRow, 3) = $_.AccessControlType.ToString();
    $c.Cells.Item($intRow, 4) = $_.FileSystemRights.ToString();
    $intRow = $intRow+1
  }
}
$d.EntireColumn.AutoFit() | Out-Null
```

Last Update:

```
$arrayOfPaths= Get-Content "\\UNC PATH\myfile.txt"

Get-ChildItem $arrayOfPaths -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.mode -match "d"} | ForEach-Object {
  $csv  = $_.FullName -replace '^\\\\[^\\]+\\([^\\]+)\\(.*)', '\\UNC PATH\Company_name_${1}_${2}.csv' # <- construct CSV path here
  $path = $_.FullName
  Get-Acl $path | Select-Object -Expand Access |
    Select-Object @{n='Path';e={$path}}, IdentityReference, AccessControlType,
                  FileSystemRights |
    Export-Csv $csv -Append -NoType
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you'd do something like this:

- loop over the paths
- get each folder's ACL
- expand the ACEs
- select the ACE properties you want exported
- add the path with a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx)
- export the selected properties to a CSV

Appending to the output CSV(s) inside the loop allows you to control to which file each ACL is exported. You can for instance make the file name depend on elements of the source path, or the number of elements already written (if you add a counter variable).

```
Get-ChildItem $arrayOfPaths | ForEach-Object {
  $csv  = "..."         # <- construct CSV path here
  $path = $_.FullName
  Get-Acl $path | Select-Object -Expand Access |
    Select-Object @{n='Path';e={$path}}, IdentityReference, AccessControlType,
                  FileSystemRights |
    Export-Csv $csv -Append -NoType
  }
}
```

Note that `-Append` was added to `Export-Csv` in PowerShell v3. On earlier versions you can sort of emulate it with `ConvertTo-Csv` and `Add-Content`.

Comment: thanks man everything is OK My question is : how can I make file name depend on elements of the source path? I assuming it's required regex expression  2- I'll get the UNC path of all the folders in a specific TXT file via Get-Content and then return each as an entry in an array? I can't figure it out.

Comment: A regular expression is the usual way. Or you could split the path string. `Get-Content` already returns an array, so you can just assign that to a variable, or directly pipe it into `Get-ChildItem`.

Comment: Am I correct above last update code? how can I combine my code with your code ? Do I have to to drop the usage of Excel as a COM-object altogether?   Also like I said before , how do I use regex or split path string ? please clarify

Comment: could you please supply sample code related to the regex expression or split path string ?thanks

Comment: You could do something like this: `$_.FullName -replace '^\\\\[^\\]+\\([^\\]+)\\(.*)', 'Company_name_${1}_${2}.csv'`.

Comment: thanks man but no luck I can't see any CSV output could you please check my code  ? There is a syntax  error ?

Comment: There are multiple UNC Paths and I'll get different CSV output for each UNC Path via for loop. At this time just its works single entry for this code.

Comment: I can't debug that for you without actual paths and/or errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122099/discussion-between-arbelac-and-ansgar-wiechers).